# Automatic converstion without access to the classes

Tags: c++, box2d, implicit-conversion, glm-math

I'm using two kinds of vectors (float x,y structs) in my engine.

One us the openGL vector, `glm::vec2`. We use this basically everywhere.

Recently we added collision with a library called Box2d. This uses `b2vec` types everywhere.

I want some way to **automatically convert** from `glm::vec2` to `b2vec` whenever I pass it into a box2d function, instead of doing it manually constantly.

Problem is: At this time **I don't have the access** to the `glm::vec2` or `b2vec` classes directly. I can't add the conversion constructors to them.

Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, automatic conversion operators must be defined as a non-static member function of the class being converted (`glm::vec2` in your case).

```
struct A {};

struct B {
    operator A();
};
```

Or, switched around, as a constructor for class `A`.

```
struct A {
    A(const B&);
};
```

The only other option is to make a non-member converter function.

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

A convert_to_A(const B&);
```